# Measure gas left in block in solidity

Tags: solidity, gas, cpp-ethereum

There is a `gasleft()` to check how much gas left for my smart contract execution in solidity. But how is it possible to check how much gas left in block?
I am having quite a big solidity function, and depending on how much gas can fit the block, next steps may differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the `gasleft()` with a loop doing something like :

```js
    do {
    // Your stuff
    } while(gasleft() > whateverYouNeed)
```

(Where `whateverYouNeed` would be the amount of gas required to run one iteration of the loop + what comes after ( maybe *1.5, just in case)

Based on this answer:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/134981/69965